# RSS feed parse from html file 

Tags: android

i have url of RSS feed [**Click here**](http://www.oxfordtimes.co.uk/news/yourtown/bicester/9628857.Golf_centre_will_become_caravan_park/r/?ref=rss) in the context of url you can see title and description over there. now i need to parse it in to android i have try to search on it but all help is regarding xml format. but here i want something like "HTML parse" and based on that perticular news description i can parse.. so is there any idea regarding those parse if yes then please help me on this...

one more thing in my searching i found that [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android) may be usefull for me and it guide me or attract to use "Apache Feedparser" so is this right way ??

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML.

It is very simple to use and well documented, you should not have too much trouble parsing your page.

---

EDIT, to point you in the right direction for parsing your page:

You should take a look at this [documentation page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

You should able to parse the title and article content with something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://.....").get();
String title = doc.select("h3").first().text(); //text in <h3> tag
String articleContent = doc.select("div.articleLeft p").toString(); //text in <p> elements nested in the <div class="articleLeft">
```

Comment: but can you tell me how can i get exactly those news detail??

Comment: becase if you right click, you show `<P>` tag are there and in one page there are multiple **p** tag so what is the idea that we can exactly fo through description?